# Asking Access Key while creating a data element

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I have created a table and am specifying the attributes. While creating the data element for the field, the system is asking for an "Access key". What is this access key and why is the system asking for it?

[image: key dialog]

Comment: Are you trying to add the element to a SAP package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a name from the implicit customer namespace (starting with Y or Z) or a reserved partner namespace. You are trying to create an object in the namespace SAP has reserved for internal product development, and to make producing collisions harder, SAP has introduced this so-called SSCR system with per-object keys.

Comment: I gave the table name as  'YNewtable'.

Comment: ...and the data element name? That's most likely the issue here.

Comment: data element name is 'de_id'.

Comment: I can see from the screenshot that this is not the case since the name ends in _DE. Even if it were so, that would be exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As vwegert said, if you want to create a new object, always start the name with `Y` or `Z`.

When you want to modify an existing SAP object (which you should only do if you have no other option), you need to register that object as modified with SAP using the [Software Change Registration app of the Support Launchpad](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/sscr/developers/my). Keep in mind that doing so will mean that SAP will no longer provide any support for any functionality which touches your modified object.